# Provide more guidance for new editors

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I see a lot of edit suggestions that do not really improve the posts they're addressing.

This makes me think we do not provide enough guidance for new editors. The situation isn't helped by the robo-reviewers; new editors are receiving a signal that they are doing well, a steady stream of "+2", because a lot of reviewers are simply too lenient.

We have an entry in the Help Center on [creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When people need help with asking questions, we can send them to Jon Skeet's famous article [How to write the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

I would like to provide new editors with a similar guideline, preferably here on Stack Overflow. It could be a separate section in the Help Center, or a canonical post on Meta.

New editors do get some guidelines in a sidebar, but I would like to provide them with a more extensive discussion. For example, we have a rule of thumb that code in a question should not be edited (even, in some cases, to "improve" the way the source is arranged), because it may accidentally remove the cause of the asker's problem. Right now you have to wade through meta to find it. I would like to provide editors with a canonical place where they can learn about this kind of thing.

Comment: So maybe creating another [meta-tag:faq] via a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] question and answer pair?

Comment: @ryanyuyu That would definitely be an option.

Comment: What about removing static like thanks.

Comment: And how would the editors be notified about that? We can easily comment on people's questions and answers to post links like the one you provided, but that's not the case with edits or results of reviews.

Comment: Really nice idea , here people normally say that editors are doing for +2 only, however new person wants to contribute but don't know he is doing it wrong.

Comment: Not that I'm apposed to the idea of creating guidelines, but giving editors better guidelines is not going to take away the apparent problem that reviewers are too lenient. If reviewers continue to be too lenient, then people have no real reason to actually read or follow the guidelines for editing. The +2's keep coming nonetheless.

Comment: @Panther: New person should read the #!@#@*&! help material. There is _plenty_ of it. New person be less lazy please.

Comment: quote (from someone....): *If you're answer to the question is "we should train the users" then your UI is wrong*

Comment: If you have any concrete suggestions, you could write up a new feature-request.

Comment: "The situation isn't helped by the robo-reviewers; new editors are receiving a signal that they are doing well, a steady stream of "+2", because a lot of reviewers are simply too lenient." It's worse than that. People well beyond the reviewable stage go on the march to the Copy Editor badge with the most wretched, thoughtless, careless editing imaginable, and nobody does (or can do) anything about it.

Comment: For me, a vast majority of my edits is removing "thanks" and such. Over half the time I use the exact note "Removed static." which I have probably edited over 50 like that.

Comment: How about requiring a short tutorial that would walk the editor-to-be through a few example edits?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I've been working on a proposed-faq (not posted yet). If you add this suggestion as an answer I would accept it. I think we don't need to shove it into a new editor's face; but if an editor gets -for example- 3 reject votes in a day, they could get a warning and a link. Just like the warning you get when you have too many declined flags. Note that I suggest counting reject _votes_, not rejects, due to the robo-reviewer problem.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm sorry I'm not clear what you want me to do.  I can edit my existing answer to include an alternate suggestion of creating more documentation for a [faq-proposed] question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu You could edit your current answer, or add a new one. I concluded that a new FAQ was the best solution here, so I want to accept an answer that suggests creating a [faq-proposed]. The part about when to show it is what I'd add if I did a self-answer here. I'll probably post it as a comment under the accepted answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth ok I worked the idea into the answer.  Feel free to edit/refine it as needed (for example, I welcome edits that include a link to your proposal once you post it).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that the information that currently would be useful to new editors and suggested-edit reviewers is scattered and too hard to find.

The help center's page for the [Edit Questions And Answers privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) under "Reviewing suggested edits" is not helpful to new reviewers.  It only mentions the mechanics of how suggested edits are approved or rejected, but it fails to give any guidelines for judging suggestions.

The other page in the help center [about the edit system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) provides these guideline for *submitting* an edit under "When should I edit posts?":

> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
>   suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
>   question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
>   reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - [A list of reasons]

---

#### My suggestion

I believe that adding a link to the ["When should I edit posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) summary in the suggested edit dropdown help would be very useful to new reviewers.  That link would also potentially be useful on the privilege page.  There are many other subtle things about suggested edits discussed in meta, but this help-page link is a good place to start.

And if you feel the help-page link is not good enough, you could also create a [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) question to summarize this kind of advice.  If it gets enough support, that post could replace the the role of the existing help-page.

Comment: Before I posted the question, I checked what happened if you edited a post anonymously, without being logged in. A shortened version of the "when should I edit" is already in the sidebar, top right. I like the idea of providing a link, but I'd like it to be more extensive.

Comment: Maybe add a negative case to compliment the *Common reasons for edits include:*? i.e. *you should **not** edit a post to: *gain reputation, etc.* Though I'm not sure if *gain reputation* should be explicitly put in, open to suggestions...

Comment: @liam Perhaps "You should not edit a post *just* to remove conversational wording like 'thanks', *just* to correct a small amount of punctuation or *just* to highlight certain words with code backticks."

Comment: Yeah, the language in the help center isn't as particular on "too minor" edits as the general consensus on meta.  Perhaps the __expected to be substantial__ could be emphasized (like this bold).

Comment: I finally got around to creating the FAQ-proposed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149

Answer (score 30):

The first time a user attempts a suggested edit, we should probably present them with some dedicated help, rather than dumping them into the live edit.

It's similar to the philosophy behind the help we provide to users asking their first question. It's a mandatory, must-read-and-click-OK type of affair.

Comment: Texts like that (How do I ask a good question, By using iTunes I agree to sell my soul to the devil, I promise to be a good editor) are agreed to without reading. They are a nuisance at best.

Comment: Then maybe the memo title *does harm* (in the Reject dialog) should be rephrased into *is problematic* or something more attractive to the reviewer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps we should have a *First Edits* review queue similar to the *First Posts* review? Then people could get personalized feedback on their edits.

Advantages over the regular review queue:

- Reviewing first edits requires the reviewer to write a comment (less robo-reviewing).
- Reviewers are more likely to see if all issues were really addressed. (When I see a substantial edit, I check for accuracy and often forget about completeness of the edit.)
- Editors are more likely to read a message that is personalized and are hopefully more likely to change their behavior because of it.

Disadvantages

- Yet another queue...
- Just the first edit gets the extra attention that all of them should.

Comment: The second disadvantage can be countered somewhat by putting (for example) the first 5 edits in a queue. You'd get hands-on guidance before editing more freely. Not sure if the personalized message would  be read - SE doesn't give notifications of rejected edits because it wants the experience to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Being a new user, I would love to have further explanation on people editing my questions/answer mainly because I didn't understand what it was. I understood the concept of them editing it but did not understand the reward there was and I feel like I did something terrible in return.

If I were to offer something I would say either have a more direct link or some form of a tutorial suggesting how to find a better edit (that actually helps). Maybe after someone has posted an edit you can edit theirs and nobody gets a point, just a better answer. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score -8):

There is plenty of guidance available.

It's just that people do not bother to read and/or heed it.

Nothing you can do other than to raise the rep requirement (which I'm not necessarily advocating, and may not even be that successful).

Comment: The guidance is spread over the system. There will always be users who can't be bothered to read the help we provide - they'll have to learn the hard way, getting edit bans. But I believe there are also those who are genuinely interested in becoming better editors, and have trouble finding all the rules and guidelines.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: They can click "Help" at the top of every single page, or take the Tour presented to them automatically upon sign-up. It's not hard.

Comment: @canon: Engaging a new user through the UI is accomplished by presenting users with reading material (unless you're planning a training day for each new user, or a video tutorial with a hidden code at the end that unlocks editing abilities, or something). Thus, my attitude is "they should read the reading material". Our approaches are actually the same, it's just that you choose to re-word mine to have unnecessary expletives in it.

Comment: As the logs in to Stack Overflow for the first time she's presented with a Tour of all of its features and of how to use it. If she cannot be bothered to read and study that material then, indeed, I have little sympathy. Whatever happened to _personal responsibility_? Gees. Everybody seems to expect to be handholded these days and, worse, _to handhold others_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "everybody seems to expect to be handholded[sic] these days" This is a question/answer site. people come here for help, recognizing a deficiency in their knowledge. I don't think it's unreasonable at all to expect edits to be of high quality. I for one had a *hard* time finding how to edit properly.

Comment: @FuriousFolder: I never said edits shouldn't be of high quality. Of course they should. I'm saying that if editors are making crappy edits then that's their fault, not ours. Chucking more reading material at them _won't help_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit chucking *any* material might. Or perhaps requiring a short tutorial that would walk the editor-to-be through a few example edits.

Comment: @FuriousFolder: These people don't read. At all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really? *I* "don't read. At all"? Funny, I would have thought my *reading the meta* would be proof to the contrary, but I guess you know best... (</sarcasm>)

Comment: @FuriousFolder: We're not talking about you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Weren't we? I thought by self-identifying as a someone who had had problems finding material on how to edit properly, I had provided an example of someone who you imply doesn't exist by saying, "These people don't read. At All.". I was of course assuming that "These people" are editors who make improper edits--something I've been guilty of in the past because of difficulty finding instruction on how to edit.