# Why was this simple edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I suggested [this simple edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9567480), so the output of the code actually matched what the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674329/python-store-letter-position/32674479#32674479) was asking for. As you can see, it was rejected for deviating from the original intent of the post, but I didn't think my edit did that (the answer was edited to something similar to mine after it was rejected). I'm just asking, because I've only very recently started using Stack Overflow actively, and I'm curious whether what I did is wrong or not, so I can improve my edits (if needed) in the future.

Comment: See also: [How to make a good edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/4320665)

Answer (score 6):

You are welcome to fix the code indent, as long as it doesn't change the codes behavior. The rest of the code in the question shouldn't be touched as it would make it harder for future readers to identify the OPs issue with the code.

If you know how to solve the issue, post an answer with the corrected code instead.

Comment: So in the future I should post my own answer with correct output instead of editing and improving an already given answer? Or should I comment under the answer (when I actually can) so the person that answered the question can improve it themselves?

Comment: You are allways free to post your own answer, especially if the already posted answers are wrong. I'd post an answer myself and comment under the wrong answer and ask the OP to improve it.