# Become a good Reviewer (Is there a Reference?)

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

Hello I'm pretty new to SO. As you can see (my rep.) I'm pretty new the review stuff too.

I've done a few review tasks, but I'm always catching myself while I'm clicking on the "SKIP" button, because I don't know how to handle this review task.

I found a lot of helpful Answers here on meta, but what I really miss is a reference like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/5297359) for PHP.

Some of you are very experienced and would say, there is no need for that, but I think to new user like me, who want to become an active and helpful member it's quite hard. Just for example, today I rejected this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10439097), but it was approved later. I wonder if I'm wrong with this reject.

There are many examples of things like that. The most appearing edits are just typos, some of you reject them, because it doesn't improve the answer, but the most will just approve them, maybe because it looks a bit cleaner?

On the other side I saw that a user deleted half the question of an OP, because he added a working solution to his question. Would this be OK? I was not sure so I skipped this, I thought you can not delete something from the OP, it's his question.

The same thing is to **flag** in a correct way, there are always the same questions. I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33867163/5297359) as an duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/5297359). But this flag is "disputed", but I think it's clearly a duplicate, because of the parse error.

As you already guess, there are more and more examples, where I can say I have to ***skip*** the review task, because I can't find something like a good reference with example reviews and some explanation.

Well like I mentioned, I found a lot of good answers here at meta, but some are really hard to find, so I would love to see such a reference like the one for PHP.

Comment: For FP/LA queue, there's [this faq-proposed Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts).  There's also this one about [making good edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), but it's not geared specifically towards review.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, thanks I already found the "make good edits", but didn't knew the other one, that's exactly what I wanted. Create a reference with some guidance and useful links like the ones from you

Comment: Yeah, the only thing is that [meta-tag:faq-proposed] questions are a lot of work,  But that could be useful.

Comment: FWIW, I skip a *lot* in some review queues. Probably not half of reviews I'm served, but I'd guess pretty close to it. If you don't know what to do, it's fine to skip it and let someone else handle it. Also, I use the filters a lot to help the system show me more things that I know how to deal with.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I understand you but I really skip about 80 percent, because I just missing some guidance, examples and explained stuff for good reviews

Comment: @swidmann that's fine.  At least you aren't messing things up with incorrect reviews.  Also, some review queues let you filter by tags, so that can help get you a set of posts that you are more familiar with.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, just found the filter link a few days ago ;) did't know that before.   I know such a question is a lot of work, but what I don't know is where to start,  Is it possible to make it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php ? How would I do that, just create a new question? Someone checks this as Wiki question or is it still a normal question?

Comment: @swidmann oddly enough, the [tag info for faq-proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info) outlines the procedure.  Basically, you make both the question and answer community wiki.  You'll need to raise a custom flag to get the question converted to a CW.  The community will hopefully contribute and/or suggest improvements.  You could potentially even convert this question to fit the faq-proposed guidelines since it doesn't have any existing answers or anything like that.  Well, once you trim the question a little bit.

Comment: IMO meta itself already has plenty of guidance to give on reviewing, you just have to find the existing questions. If you want to create your own faq then that will be an invaluable source of information.Good luck with that though, I wouldn't be able to put something so heavily driven by intelligence and patience into any coherent form.

Comment: ryanyuyu, this helps a lot, thank you. @Gimby yes I agree the coherent form will be the biggest problem.