# When a edit is overlapped, over an other edit, why does the earlier edit be rejected?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

So, I had edited three questions, which were overlapped by another edit. Thus, they were rejected. Afterwards, when I went to do another edit, I got a warning on the top saying that my earlier edits were rejected, and thus, I had a chance of getting banned from editing.

Now, all my edits were useful, but they got rejected because of another edit by another user overlapping my edit. Because of this, I had nearly got banned from editing, because of no reason.

**Feature Request**

Because of this, one user might get banned from editing, even if all his edits were of good quality. So there are a lot of options we can work out here:

- When an edit is pending, another user cannot edit that post.
- If an edit gets overlapped, instead of marking the original edit as `rejected`, put something like `overlapped`, in which the user will not get any rep, and it will not be counted as accepted or rejected. Thus, not leading to an misjudgment of the edit.
- Let both the edits be pending, and be reviewed. If both the edits are not agreeing with each other, let it be reviewed which is better.

In my opinion, I would go with the second option. Not the first option because, it is possible that the first edit is of poor quality, or the second edit is adding might be also useful. Not the third as it is to expensive.

Comment: IIRC rejected edits with reason conflicting edit don't count against you in edit-ban heuristics (the only one that matters in conjunction with suggested edits) anyways. Furthermore, why do you think users with full edit privileges should not be able to edit a post when another edit is pending?

Comment: So in essence your second suggestion is already implemented in everything but name.

Comment: @Magisch, I had not been getting a warning, till these three edits were rejected as they were overlapped, and then I started getting the warning. So how can it be not because of that? If you want you can check my edit history, in my main user.

Comment: @Magisch, right now, I edited two more questions, and I am still getting the warning.

Comment: You have a total of 5 rejected edits, 3 rejected because of conflicting edits, 1 because of a [Reject and Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11183592) action from a reviewer and one from [a reject review from 3 users](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11144311)

Comment: Thats enough to trigger the warning, but by and large nowhere near enough to trigger an edit suspension. It is maintained that the conflicting subsequent edit reviews don't count against you.

Comment: A while ago, I [proposed a FAQ for editors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), to put all the advice for editing in one place. Following the advice there may help you avoid an edit ban.