# If I choose "Improve Edit" when reviewing suggested edits, does the original editor earn reputation?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, I sometimes see a minor improvement that I could make, like a grammar fix or removing "thanks" or "I am new to *insert technology here>*..."

If I choose "Improve Edit" to remove these relatively minor issues, does the original editor get the points?

Comment: yes, and that's why I *reject and edit* if there are multiple things missing.

Comment: Awesome. That is what I hoped to hear.

Comment: So I've been suggesting edits for a few weeks now. I've been suggesting normal things like code blocks, spacing, grammatical errors, etc. I have never, however, removed things like "thanks", "I am new", "Please help". Should these be removed?

Comment: @DanielK Yes, various "Thanks", greetings or other fluff should be removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @DanielK Perhaps that's a manner of style, but I'd prefer questions that are to the point and as free from irrelevant info as possible. My understanding, is the these questions have roughly three purposes: 1. answer the original OP's problem, serve as a tool to aid people performing internet searches on the same / similar issues; 3. serve as something of a check box to fill in gaps of previously unanswered questions on SO. To help serve the second and third purposes, clarifying the title, reformatting the text for easier reading, and "removing noise" as someone once said are improvements.

Comment: I see a healthy amount of debate in that question, so there is definitely a disagreement on how it should be handled. I still do appreciate the human touch but also understand the need to remove noise. I think a good middle ground is leave things like "Hi" or "thanks" but remove things like "I need this now" or "I am a newbie". Thoughts?

Comment: Personally, I prefer to remove salutations and demands, but leave *some* indication of skill level. As long as it is not too distracting. Knowing the asker's skill level often factors into my response. When working with a self-professed novice, I am more attuned to common errors and gotchas they may have overlooked.  I also try and provide a bit more background, about why doing `x` instead of `y` is recommended.

Comment: @DanielK. My own rule of thumb is to remove such stuff *only if I'm already editing the post anyway*. I would never edit merely to remove thanks.

Comment: @DanielK There is indeed a lot of discussion over that point, but a great deal of it comes when people *only* edit out the "thanks" and do nothing else - edits bumps the post to the front page.  The best consensus I've seen is to edit those out, but only while you're at it editing other things as well, it's listed in an this faq [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

Comment: @Ajean, I see your point and I agree. With that said, edits are definitely a point of disagreement in the community. I edited a post yesterday clearly made by a non-english speaker. I fixed his grammar, punctuation & general cohesiveness. My post was approved 3-1, the dissenter listed the reason that I did not do enough & may be harming the post quality. Looking at his history he rejects far more than he approves so can't please them all I suppose.

Comment: @DanielK Indeed! And you should probably know, the suggested edits queue is *particularly* well-known for terrible reviewers, that approve things they really shouldn't and reject perfectly good edits.  So don't let any one particular edit or how it does in review get you confused :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Yes, they do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

> #### What does the "Improve Edit" button do?
>
> [...]
>
> - The original editor still gets +2 reputation for their suggestion.

Do note that:

> When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2
> reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total
> cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000. Like any other
> reputation, the +2 is reversed if the edited post is ever deleted.

Comment: Hrm, just curious about the "ever deleted" part. I know I shouldn't waste my time polishing up off topic stuff, but is an edit reputation gain subject to eternal potential loss? I mean if I edit a question and that question is later decided to be off topic a few years from now, and it gets deleted, is that reputation from the edit lost?

Comment: @BoogaRoo That is correct. If a suggested-edit that earned you +2 reputation is deleted (the day after or 10 years after), the reputation is reversed.