# Does Improve Edit in Suggested Edits review queue award points to suggester?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I bumped into a post on a review queue today where I thought the edit by the submitter did improve the code formatting (indentation), but also saw something a little non-standard so I improved the edit. I was hoping it would not disenfranchise the original submitter, e.g. would still give them reputation credit for the suggested edit, and assumed it would, but wanted to verify that. It wasn't a critical change, so I would have forgone my own edit to improve the post if I thought it would work against the submitter.

I've been looking through some of the threads on Meta regarding suggested edits to get a conclusive answer, and from what I can tell "Improve Edit" is not treated like a rejection. However I didn't see anything that explicitly described its behavior.  And while I saw one answer to a question that described some of the history of the Suggested Edits review queue, that made a proposal for changes to it, the current review queue scheme doesn't match the proposal tightly, so I decided to ask.

Unfortunately, as I reviewed 20 Suggested Edits today, the category is greyed out so I can't go back now and review the category help text to see if it is explained there at the moment (nor do I see any way to see review queue progress/goals popup when a category is greyed out, but that's another topic).

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325963/if-i-choose-improve-edit-when-reviewing-suggested-edits-does-the-original-edi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "improve edit" immediately approves the suggested edit (granting +2 to the editor if they qualify), and then submits your improvement as a follow-up revision.

#### See also: [Editing is essential: new badges and review enhancements](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)

Comment: On a similar note, I've often wondered what messaging the editor gets for suggestions that were improved. For rejections (that the reviewer also edits) I think they are told to view the revision history to see what they missed. Do they get anything similar for an improved suggestion?

Comment: Not unless you leave a comment @-notifying them. Which, if the edit is approved / improved, you *can* do.