# When does the temporary editing ban get lifted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I recently got banned for editing posts and wanted to know if I will be notified when the ban is lifted or what measures can I take to lift the ban soon.

Comment: You should have received a notice when the ban expires when you attempt to make a suggested edit. Anyway, the system will automatically lift the ban in 2 days.

Comment: Recently the implementation has been made for maximum of 20 posts. Check what happened to your recent edits. 4+ rejected edits in a span of one week.

Comment: @JonClements: Its been 5 days since I got banned. No actions yet.

Comment: @KrishMunot so you've got 2 days left of a 7 day ban then...

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by [Jon Clements's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329131/when-does-the-temporary-editing-ban-get-lifted#comment371365_329131), when you attempt to suggest an edit, a notice will be displayed containing the ban's expiration date.

In your case, the ban was for 7 days and was automatically lifted after that. You'll not be notified when it is lifted, but you'll find that you're no longer blocked when trying to suggest an edit.

For moderator-imposed bans, there are no measures for you to take to lift the ban any sooner. While banned, you are invited to review your past edit actions to make sure you don't make the same mistakes again. You might also study other material like [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)