# Capitalizing i's

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, edits

I have two points here.

1. I would like to point out that people who post their questions with lowercase i's for no reason make their questions unprofessional. It feels like they put very little effort into posting their questions. Examples can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883731/android-googleapi-v2-keep-looking-for-gps-position), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883754/screen-sharing-js-how-to-avoid-capturing-mouse-pointer), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883777/selenium-grid-script-in-c-sharp-error). It doesn't irk me enough to change it, but if I am already editing the post I would switch it because reading something like that on a professional site is annoying. Yes, it might not change the clarity of the question, but we are encouraged and should follow what grammar rules that we do know as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) says.
2. Can Stack Overflow make some kind of site wide script to fix these types of posts? Obviously it would have to exclude code segments :) or we would have major problems.

Comment: You mention 3 examples, and all 3 are in my opinion ... not that very good questions, are they? Respectively, "Too broad", "Off topic", and "My Code Is Not Working, Plz Fix". While your "if I'm already editing" point is correct, don't bother [polishing turds](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/2564301).

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange

Comment: i think u need 2 chillax ;)

Comment: If questions with a lot of uncapitalized "I's" were automatically closed as "unclear what you're asking", I bet the false positive rate would be fairly reasonable. Most of such questions that I see are also littered with grammatical and spelling errors that they do make the question unclear.

Comment: I'm joking of course. I don't like the txtspk all over the place either, but then again, I also don't like the emoticons in questions either :).

Comment: I can live with the i's, but can someone please fix the [bellow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bellow)s?

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe this should be on Stack Overflow to fix these types of grammatical issues.  [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) wrote a great userscript to fix trivial grammar errors like these called the [Magic™Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js) if you feel so inclined to help a user by editing their post into shape.

When you get to 2k reputation, you will be able to edit posts directly without going through the review queue.

Comment: I know that but I don't want to sit there fixing carelessness when it should be the OPs job. Since we can't enforce that at least we can have a script.

Comment: @A_Arnold why are you so concerned about this specific grammar rule?  Don't you think the Stack Overflow team has more pressing issues to work on, such as keeping their site online?

Comment: it feels like it would be so easy to correct and I am ok if people don't know grammar rules but this just feels like negligence.

Comment: @A_Arnold And what if the question is about fixing grammar errors and gives one as an example? The script goes through, fixes it, and oops! The OP's question doesn't make sense anymore. Better to use a tool yourself and scan it yourself, rather than let an automated process potentially break posts. "i" specifically is used as a short variable in code often. There are too many chances to break posts with a script to automatically correct grammar issues. (Even excluding code blocks there are just too many chances to break posts.)

Comment: @Kendra I specifically noted the code problem in my question.

Comment: @A_Arnold Those chances to break won't always appear in code. Someone could inline quote ("") their example or they could block quote their example, as an example. They can write an "i" in quotes, like I've been doing, and mean their variable. There are too many chances for this to break.

Comment: @Kendra I hear you. It would be nice to find a solution to this besides for manual editing. It is very common in newer users to just post questions like these.