# Warn about it when someone omits the space between "Stack" and "Overflow" or miscapitalizes them

Tags: feature-request, spelling, grammatical-correction

Some users consistently forget to separate the words "Stack" and "Overflow" using a space, thus calling Stack Overflow "StackOverflow".

Some of them take one step further and capitalize the F of "Overflow", which results in "StackOverFlow"!

1. Isn't this annoying?
2. The regex `StackOver[fF]low` can detect such errors with (almost) no false positives. It shouldn't be hard to check if a post/comment matches it <strike>before being posted</strike> and warn the poster about it.

Comment: It is the name of a programming bug and exception, auto-correcting it to the name of a company makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Even if this is only implemented for Meta (I don't see why it would be needed for the main site), it's _really_ not a hard error to fix... (And [Peter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen) normally finds and fixes it decently fast, if no one else does.)

Comment: One flowed over the cuckoo's stack...

Comment: Realted: [Capitalizing i's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332142/2415822)

Comment: Even annoying things that are easy to fix should not be fixed automatically. They are a signal that there is probably something else wrong with the post, so it should be left to a human editor.

Comment: Who favorited this?

Answer (score 17):

> The regex StackOver[fF]low can detect such errors with no false positives.

Except for when your language of choice uses Pascal case and *actually* has a `StackOverflow` exception or error.

I don't see why this should be automated.  Simply comment or edit it.