# Suggested edit rejected by OP as "product promotion / destructive"

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14406905) to a question to fix both grammar, tabbing, and general formatting. I made these changes because as I was reading through the question I was unable to clearly understand what the user was asking, so I figured that fixing formatting and grammar would help the OP get better answers quickly (fixing the tabbing was just because it bugged me).

The edit was rejected by the OP as:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

If you look at the edit, I don't believe it was destructive, and it was definitely not promoting anything. What did I do incorrectly in my edit, so I don't make that mistake again?

Answer (score 51):

Unfortunately (in this case), the OP has the power to single-handedly reject a suggested edit, for any reason he/she likes.

Still, even with the edit, the question is still unclear (for example, where in the code does the OP call the `start()` method? Where is the stack trace?). [Don't try to polish turds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/4751173) – it's better to move on and try to help somebody who actually *wants* to be helped.