# What if edits are rejected by community?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

While editing a question, if the community rejects your edit, is this sign of disapproval for further edits?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit

Answer (score 6):

A rejection by the Community User can mean two things:

One reason is that another editor, who had full editing privileges (i.e. above 2000 rep) edited the post at the same time. And since they have full editing privileges, their edit gets preference.
This is what happened to the edit you probably refer to, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15591036): "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".
This is nothing to worry about.

The other reason is when a reviewer chooses "Reject & Edit". Then, the reviewer decides that an edit suggestion is bad, and that they would rather use their own edit instead. Then you will see a message saying that the edit did not resolve crucial parts of the post. This *is* reason to consider your editing. It means that one user disapproved of your edit - and it's possible they *strongly* disapproved of the edit. If this happens a lot, then it may be better to stop editing.

On the whole, your edits look good, but there are a few things to consider.

- You should capitalize the first person personal pronoun - it's "I", not "i".
- In [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15590401), the word "because" was properly spelled; your edit misspelled it. Also, adding "this happen" at the end was grammatically incorrect.

I once [proposed a FAQ for editors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149). It's not an official FAQ, but you might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and valuable answer for my question  ;)@S.L. Barth

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about whole community then consistent rejection of your edit suggestion will lead you to edit ban.

From [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> What happens if someone suggests a bad edit?
>
> If a user without edit privileges proposes an edit that does not
>   comply with the guidelines above, it is ordinarily rejected in the
>   review process. Even if a bad edit is applied to a post, other users
>   will generally fix it. Users with sufficient reputation may elect to
>   roll back the post to a previous version (by viewing the revision
>   history of the post and selecting the version they would like to
>   display).
>
> Additionally, any user who submits many rejected edits will be banned
>   from suggesting further edits for 7 days.

Or rejection by community user:

Community user generally rejects edit when someone with privilege of edit without approvals, edits the post which overrule your edit suggestion waiting in approval to be rejected.