# Should I remove the UI toolkit from a question where it is irrelevant to make it more general?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Sometimes I find [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions where a UI toolkit ([swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing), [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx), etc.) is mentioned, but is irrelevant to the question. These questions often say they have a project in Java using a given UI toolkit and then there is no reference to UI toolkit classes or concepts. Should I remove references to this UI toolkit to make the question more general?

I am asking because recently [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24031499) was rejected on the question *[Google transliteration API in Java Swing project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9134899/1651107)*. I wanted to remove the UI toolkit from this question, because I wanted to mark other similar questions as duplicate, but other question used different toolkits.

There were two (contradictory) reasons for rejection:

1. My edit was superfluous
2. My edit changed intent of question

Thinking about it, there is one case where UI toolkit might be relevant - [gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt). GWT is special, because it is about the UI on the client side of a web application and has many unrelated concepts to standard desktop UI applications. GWT allows Java and JavaScript on the client side (with some limitations). So in my case of edit, by removing Swing might I have made question too general (since a solution for GWT client-side JavaScript code would apply too)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific technology, but IMO as someone who works in the review queues: The information does not *hurt* the question, does provide more complete information about the OP's environment and, as far as the OP knows, it *could* be relevant to the problem. Rather more facts than fewer... So I'd have probably rejected such an edit, as well.

Comment: @CindyMeister while information does not hurt, it makes question more specific. I am talking about cases where It is clear this information is irrelevant (but I understand it may not be clear to others or OP).

Comment: Just my opinion, of course, but if you feel it detracts from the central point, perhaps an edit to put it at the end as sort of "my system configuration is:..."?

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with the tech, but that question seems awfully broad; "how do I hook up Google's transliteration API?" No attempts to do so in the question, just a couple of links (one of which is a tutorial on how to hook up Google's transliterate API). You might be "polishing a turd" there. See [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/215552)