# Temporarily suspended from suggesting edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have been banned and I don't understand why.
I have only tried to improve the tags of the posts I usually work with, for a better search or response.

> Suggested Edits You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits -
> please review your edit history.

I don't spam and I avoid all that. I don't understand what I have done wrong.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you reviewed [your edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9446515/jatniel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), as suggested by the message?

Comment: Suggested edits need to be reviewed by other users and therefore should be substantial and not just add some tags (that may or may not be relevant) but strive to correct also post body and title to avoid wasting other users' time.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/11682469)

Comment: What I have done in the messages is to suggest one or more tags, I have not edited the message.
thanks yivi & jeanne-dark

Comment: you have ~60% of your suggested edits rejected: the formula, AFAIK, is: `If (rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5, you will be auto-banned.`

Comment: @Jatniel - NP, there is a semi-obscure Uber Meta Q&A about this (I am not sure if the formula was ever amended): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/786798

Comment: @Jatniel - Substantial edits are typically more than just adding tags to a question.  Perhaps you should focus on substantial edits instead of adding tags, considering, more than a majority of your proposed edits were rejected by the community

Comment: Anyways, now you just need to wait a bit. In the meantime, please take into account (and I am speaking as a person very active in the suggested edits review queue) that edits should not: 1. Be tag-only unless it is *really* the only thing to improve (leave this to users with full edit privileges). 2. Leave "thank you", "I am new to", "Can you help me?" and other noise. 3. Skip formatting issues. There is more guidance in the post linked by Jeanne

Comment: **Thank you all very much for your help.**

P.S.: I've done something novice, but so many negative votes is it necessary?

Comment: @Jatniel - nah, don't worry about it, here on Meta that's to be expected :) Despite some may tell you that DVs on meta mean disagreement only on feature requests, it does not work this way. You won't be post-banned or lose rep for it. The takeaway should be the answers and comments you got to help you avoid this issue in the future, so all is well

Answer (score 21):

You solve that by not suggesting edits that are bound to get rejected.

Let's look at one and I leave the [other rejections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit) for you to study.

This is the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28727373)

Notice the reject reason:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

Adding that tag doesn't help, no matter if you say *add while-loop to good search and reponse*. I doubt PHP tag followers will also filter on while-loop.

Let's take a look at the post itself. Without the code the first paragraph read:

> I have following code,i try to style output with css,but i have small problem,my code show all database entries,which is ok,but when i remove comment from WHILE loop,and comment echo,its showing only first row of entries from database..how can i do same thing and show multiple results from database by use variables in While loop??:

There is a lot to fix there. If you suggest an edit: Fix as much as you reasonably can.

Just using some basic English grammar rules and the spelling checker of Chrome I can come up with this:

> I have the following code. I try to style the output with CSS but I have a small problem. My code shows all database entries which is okay but when I remove the comment from the while loop and comment echo it is showing only the first row of entries from the database.
>
> How can I do the same thing and show multiple results from the database by use of variables in a while loop?

That suggested edit might have seen a better reception and with some more love I can noise reduce it even more.

Don't just retag for the sake of re-tagging.

Use the time your ban lasts to read-up on [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), install a good spelling checker, checkout  edits made by others. If you spend that time well you'll not end-up banned again.

Comment: Thank you very much @rene for your information and answer.

I will be more aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 17):

You are spending a lot of time adding poor or irrelevant tags to questions that are themselves poor. Since your reputation is below 2,000 every one of your edits has to be reviewed by at least one person, and a high proportion of those edits have been rejected, which has triggered the auto-ban algorithm.

In short, the Stack Overflow algorithms have determined that you are harming more than helping. What did you do wrong?

---

- Don't add irrelevant tags to questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28682069 was correctly rejected for this reason:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

The question contains references to Ubuntu and SSH, but those are entirely irrelevant to its actual topic (and should probably be edited out). Therefore, adding [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) and [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) was incorrect.

- Don't add tags to questions that should be closed.

The question at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28709732 was downvoted twice and eventually closed, as it simply doesn't contain enough information to be answerable. There is no use spending any sort of time editing such questions, unless you're the author.

- Don't add poor tags to questions.

The tag [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) you tried to add to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28661014 is a poor tag, because it's so generic and assigned to so many questions already that it's effectively worthless for narrowing down search results.

Ideally we would remove such large junk tags, but mechanisms for doing so have not been made available to us curators, and people keep recreating them anyway.

- Don't edit questions only to add or remove tags.

As the Help Centre states:

> Edits are expected to be **substantial** and to leave the post better than you found it.

(emphasis mine).

If you find a question you believe needs editing, you must be prepared to fix **everything** you can see wrong with it. Since every edit you make needs to be reviewed, the fewer edits you make lowers the load on reviewers.

---

There is far more to being a good Stack Overflow curator than tagging; in fact, tags are arguably one of the *least* important parts of a question. Concentrate on fixing question bodies - spelling, grammar, and code formatting - **before** you look at the tags.

Comment: I guess you could say that adding more generic tags to an already correctly tagged question is doing the post a disservice. You want the combination of tags to reach the smallest number of possible answerers to increase the chance on a correct answer. Not sure how this fits easily in applicable guidance for editors that are just starting out on SO. Your guidance is probably the best we can do for now.

Comment: "tags are arguably one of the least important parts of a question" I wouldn't put it so broadly, if a question has the wrong tag(s) then it will likely not find an audience so they are pretty vital actually. You are probably talking more about how important it is to edit them.

Comment: Thank you very much @ian-kemp for your information and answer.