# Is it okay to edit others' questions & answers often?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently I learnt about the edit feature. I improved a few questions and answers that I thought weren't good and clear. After a while I started wondering if I am editing too much.

Is it okay to edit many times on Stack Overflow? Will I get my permission to edit taken away if I edit too many times? What makes me ask this question is the fact that you get **+2 rep** every time you edit, and editing more may make it seem like I am working hard to get reputation. So as a concluding question, is it okay to edit other people's questions and answers on Stack Overflow many times?

By *many* I mean something like editing 6-7 times per day.

Comment: 6-7 times per day is not ***a lot***. If you really believe a post can be improved, you are encouraged to edit it. Your edit needs to be approved by the community, so if your edits are not good you will not get the rep. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): *"Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so."*

Comment: What matters is the quality of the suggested edits. Also relevant: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899), [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/11682469)

Comment: As long as the edits are good edits and they address the issues in the post, 6-7 is a day is fine. I often edit many times more than that in a day.

Comment: Edits should definitely be punished - you can find [the list of the worst offenders here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors). Joking aside, just make *meaningful* edits and do not make *cosmetic* edits to posts that have much bigger issues - if you follow that, not only will you be fine but praised for making the valuable contribution to the network - editing posts in shape is a venerable occupation.

Comment: If you keep editing the same post, there's a problem. But it's probably not your problem. It's the writer's.

Comment: I edited your title once, because of course it is not okay to edit posts "too many times". Once you've reached "too many" it is by definition of "too", not okay.

Comment: From the other end, of course I appreciate good editing to make one of my questions better. I have had, on occasion, been plagued by edits which change the nature of my question, or impose stylistic changes I disagree with. Just be sure you don’t develop a reputation for hijacking questions.

Comment: @Prabhdeep side note from a fellow editor: many of your edits add large Markdown headings above blocks of code. [This formatting is mostly unnecessary/distracting, and the community generally frowns upon it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214427/is-using-header-markdown-okay-in-answers), so I would advise not forming a habit of it. Keep up the rest of the good work!

Comment: 6-7 times a day is pretty mild. I just edited about 50 wiki posts last night to earn the [assistant badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant). It's not about the number of edits, there is no upper limit, but rather the quality of the edit itself. And there is no shame in working hard to get more reputation and badges. They are one of the reasons Stackoverflow is so popular nowadays, because people get attracted to the fake internet points for some reasons (myself include).

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Suggesting edits is actually one of the best ways to earn rep: many bots gain the 20 required for chat by suggesting ten edits. Nothing to be ashamed about.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your editing privileges will be taken away from you if you don't edit enough. I am just joking.

There are [rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/515960) imposed on pretty much all actions one can do on Stack Overflow. You can't submit more than 5 suggested edits at a time. Until you reach 2000 reputation points, we kindly ask you to make your suggested edits really meaningful as they need to be reviewed by other people. When your suggested edit gets approved, the system will reward your contribution with 2 reputation points and you can submit another edit.

You can only get reputation from the first 500 approved suggested edits on non-deleted posts. You can suggest more edits, but the system will not reward you anymore.

Once you reach 2000 reputation points, you will be able to instantaneously edit posts. As long as you don't edit a few hundred posts per minute *, you should be ok. However, please be mindful that your edits still have some impact on others. They bump posts in "active" first search. They trigger notifications for people following them. You can edit more and do it quicker, but do it with respect for other users of the site.

Furthermore, it's not only ok to edit other people's posts, but it's the right thing to do. If you see something that would improve the readability of the post, please suggest an edit. It will help future readers.

<sub>* It's rather impossible as <10k users will trigger captcha when editing more than 2 posts per minute and >10k users 6 posts per minute.</sub>

Comment: However, do not change the author's intent when editing. (I could add this to your answer as an edit, for irony)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure I didn't break the captcha?

Comment: "It's rather impossible as <10k users will trigger captcha when editing more than 2 posts per minute and >10k users 6 posts per minute." How strong is the captcha? There are bots that will automatically fill in weaker captcha systems now.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: no one will object to you making an unclear post more clear. In fact, that's exactly why you get reputation for editing: you're helping future readers by making the Q&A repository better.

The only case case where this would be a problem is if you were repeatedly editing the same post for the purpose of gaining the reputation system, but that doesn't seem to be the case here (since you indicated that you were trying to improve unclear content).