# Why was my question edited for style?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I recently posted a question and it was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72143336/revisions) within about 15 minutes for what are essentially stylistic word choices, mostly making the wording slightly more concise. Is this standard practice that I just haven't noticed before?

As a one-off, it’s not a big deal. However, having questions edited for what seems like essentially a disagreement on style as opposed to clarity (or some other better metric) makes this seem like a less friendly place to post questions.

Comment: The more concise (but not less intelligible) a question is, the easier it is to answer. _"I'm creating a model with scikit-learn"_ is a just a little bit easier to process than _"I'm creating a model and I'm using scikit learn for it."_

Comment: _...but I'm hoping to there is a way to do this within the sklearn framework_ seems to have grammatical issues. So, it isn't entirely about style

Comment: I think the edit makes the question clearer. Rather than interpreting it as unfriendly, try to see it as someone helping you to ask your question.

Comment: Also, beware of [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/17242583) :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit). The guidelines on editing posts perfectly answer your question about this being standard practice.

Comment: @zcoop98 superfluous it may be by some opinions; but the OP does not ask about that. They claim that such edits make the site less friendly, which (to me at least) is a puzzling statement.

Comment: As usual, it all comes down to incorrectly setting expectations about what we are, @desertnaut. Until the company makes it loud and clear that we are a Q&A spin on Wikipedia for programmers and not a forum, we are going to receive such puzzling statements...

Comment: "However, having questions edited for what seems like essentially a disagreement on style as opposed to clarity (or some other better metric) makes this seem like a less friendly place to post questions." - While you are the contributing author by submitting the question originally, you are the sole owner of the question, that honor belongs to the entire community.  It's the job of the community to edit questions, when it's appropriate, so they will eventually be answered.  **Your question needed to be edit, the edit that your question receive, should be seen as a positive thing.**

Comment: Re: the question about policy (in my first paragraph), thanks all for the links. I agree completely, this edit was in line with the policy. @desertnaut I can see why it seems puzzling. I'll reply directly to your answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I confess I am puzzled that such an edit (disclosure: mine) ends up being perceived as making the site less friendly.

As others have already pointed out in the comments, the idea was simply to make the question clearer, more concise, and to correct some grammatical errors, in the spirit of *mutual help*. For example, the initial post was

> I'm hoping to there is a way to do this within the sklearn framework. Does anyone know a way?

Apart from some obvious grammatical errors, your actual question is arguably not if anyone knows (which could be provocatively answered simply with a "*Yes, I do know*", without anything further); similarly, what you are hoping or not is actually irrelevant and just adds clutter.

Compare this to the edited

> is there a way to do this within sklearn?

So, no grammatical errors, no irrelevant hopes etc, and the *actual* question brought forward.

Again, I am puzzled that it became such a big deal, and certainly this was nowhere close to my intentions (which intentions, in accordance to the site's relevant [rules & guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), were to *help* improving a post).

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. As regards the content of the edit: I'm not sure I see the "obvious" grammatical error, but I believe you when you say there is such an error. With the rest of it (that someone could reply "Yes, I do know" or that there is clutter) - yes, this is technically correct, but seems pedantic (though I freely admit that is also a matter of personal taste).

Comment: As regards the broader question: I certainly didn't mean to imply that you were being unfriendly - more that this type of edit, in general, can make the site seem less friendly. This may not be the best way to express it, but small edits like this provoke the same feeling as when spending time with someone who constantly corrects small mistakes in conversation.  To be honest, I didn't think my question would receive so much negative feedback. In any event, I appreciate you trying to make SO better and within the policy. I'll just need to get on board with policy so I can keep using the site.

Comment: @roundsquare Beware of dubious analogies: posts here are not analogous to oral conversations (where a behavior such as the one you describe would indeed be frustrating). Our posts (both questions and answers) here do not even "belong" to us in a sense; here we aim to build a repository of high-quality Q&As which will remain and be useful for others in the future, not to be a forum or a help desk (the term "wikipedia of programming" used in the comments above is a good metaphor). Hence, it makes sense to clean posts & remove irrelevant (and unnecessary) clutter.

Comment: that's understood. I wasn't making making a direct analogy. As stated, I was merely trying to give an idea of the feeling evoked, not saying that the action under discussion is directly analogous. Perhaps this is, as stated by Oleg above, a misapprehension regarding the nature of this site.

Comment: PS in the comment above when I said "To be honest, I didn't think my question would receive so much negative feedback." I was referring to my question here, not the original question.

Comment: Negative feedback on Meta sites mean that people disagree with you. That's hardly unexpected; collaborative editing is an integral principle of this site, and has been since the beginning. We are, in a lot of ways, like Wikipedia. The "wiki" aspect is strong, and we're also building a knowledge base. We're just doing it a bit differently, structuring it in the form of bite-sized questions and answers. Fortunately, downvotes on Meta have no effect on your reputation (or anything else), so they just serve as a noise-free proxy for gauging community sentiment. @roundsquare

Comment: There isn't any need to be puzzled. Users are not on-boarded properly and think they are on a forum (which [Stack Exchange is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115)). The [CEO doesn't make it any easier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s). You did the right thing. Though the intent could have been made clear in the edit summary.