# Small edit with the removal of product name considered as a bad edit, why?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit, reject-reasons

I recently suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32544531) and it was rejected for not improving the quality of the post. I removed the name of the game since it's not necessary and is irrelevant. How does that not impact (or reduce) the quality of the post? Why was this edit rejected?

Comment: Your edit didn't solve all of the problems in that post, there are several grammatical mistakes that you didn't rectify.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so if I need to edit a post, and if other problems I can fix exist, should I also fix them?

Comment: @Random absolutely **yes**! Fix everything you can; grammar, spelling, formatting, titles, tags. If you only fix one thing, and the post is littered with spelling mistakes (for example), then it *should* be rejected. Call me pedantic but I get quite annoyed when editors don't capitalise `I` throughout the post.

Comment: Please try to fix as many as the egregious errors as you can. Just removing one thing is not enough. There are several more grammatical errors in that post that somebody else has to fix after you. It's OK if you missed small things but not if you omit big ones. The suggested edits queue is *straining* under too many too trivial edits. One of the things that can improve the situation is not make tiny almost irrelevant suggestions.

Comment: When editing a post, you should be addressing all the problems with it. As @AbdulAzizBarkat notes, there are several problems with the post. The part you removed was noise, but you fail the address the lack of capitalisation of "i", didn't correct "dont" to "don't" or improve the readability for others (as the text is written in "broken English"). As the decline reason said: *"The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary"* My opinion (as one of the reviewers) was that it didn't improve the quality.

Comment: Echoing others, always try to make your edits as complete as possible; take a look at our [FAQ post for how to make a good edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220).

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? 3 downvotes means that there is something I should improve, or is this a duplicate? Or is this not the kind of question to ask here? As understandable from the question itself, I don't really know what determines the quality of an edit or a question even after reading related questions and help center things.

Comment: Votes on meta are different, @Random . They can also denote the (dis)agreement with the question/answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you didn't fix:

- Obvious non-capitalization of "I" as a proper noun
- Sentence flow and poor grammar

  > for some reasons dont work even if output give no errors

Who *cares* about the name of the thing being removed?  Of all of the issues in the post that one was of the lowest consequence.  People nickname their projects all the time.