# Why are my suggested edits not getting approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have suggested edits to the answers to 2 different questions (answered by other people) but each time, my suggested edits to the answer are not approved even though I have added sensible changes in the answer (without modifying the original answer) with the intent of having the answer up-to-date as per latest tech and dependencies.

What should be done in this scenario?

It would be better if the person reviewing someone's answer would actually provide a meaningful reason as to why the edit was approved or even declined (which would help the person submitting an update to further optimize their answer). I request Stack Overflow to take it as a new feature request and implement it if not done yet.

Comment: Your edits are far beyond what the author intended. Post your own answer, credit any other answers/sources you quote/paraphrase. [help]

Comment: Also avoid using UPDATE. Posts should read as if they were written once, no matter how many times they have been edited. If we want to see the sequence of edits we can look at the edit history.

Comment: Also, if one of your edits is rejected, please don't just suggest the same edit again.

Comment: You are adding unnecessary commentary like “update” despite the fact any user can tell the contribution had been updated. You also added in your own content, to another users contribution, potentially changing the authors intent. You’re not submitting proposals that should be approved. “ This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.” - is perfectly clear

Answer (score 1):

The do's and don'ts of editing are [pretty well-established](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit).

What I read more into this meta post is that you don't even consider the possibility that you could have been mistaken, everything that has happened was being done to you and other people need to do things to shield you from that.

Well you are wrong. You were using Stack Overflow as you pleased, not as intended. Stack Overflow is the poster example of not focusing on what you *can* do, the only thing that is relevant is if you *should* do it. Just radically changing answers is a pretty well-documented thing not to do. Yet you were doing it unquestionably.

What are you going to do now to shield you from yourself? Read and learn, I hope.