# Advice for new Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts reviewers

Tags: discussion

Having just ticked over the 2k reputation mark I'd like some advice on getting started with reviews in the LQP, Suggested Edits, and H&I queues.

There is a good link on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) about getting started with the Late Answers & First Posts queues, but nothing about the others that I could see from a very quick search.

I also see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299642/provide-more-guidance-for-new-editors) discussion about better/more advice for new editors but it's not clear that it ever got turned into a faq-request or anything like that.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295319/provide-more-guidelines-for-reviewing-edits) discussion was quite useful and my main take-away points are roughly:

- Reject or skip all & any code edits unless I'm willing to check every char individually. - This was not relating to making code formatted and readable, this was more aimed at where entire chunks of code have been changed, or the code has been re-typed from an image upload by someone.
- Reject or skip any 'to English' translations. Unless I'm willing to check the translation personally.
- Reject all the really trivial stuff like 'i' to 'I' - but in this case should I reject & edit myself to correct it and anything else I can see, or just reject it?
- VLQ - I should 'skip' any reviews unless I specifically know about the subject area.

As for the other queues I'm looking for some meta wisdom on how best to make a start.

Comment: "*Reject all & any code edits unless I'm willing to check every char individually.*" that sounds terrible. Very often the code edits are making something barely legible into a properly formatted code that other people can look at and understand without difficulty. Rejecting those out of spite is wasting A LOT more people's times than yours.

Comment: "*Reject all the really trivial stuff like 'i' to 'I' - but in this case should I reject & edit myself to correct it and anything else I can see, or just reject it*" if you're going to reject and edit to do *the same change* with nothing else, then...why not just accept the edit? You clearly think this is exactly what the post needs.

Comment: my concern with code was looking for things which got broken in the edit especially if there are no comments. I wasn't so much thinking about code formatting, but more where code has either been completely changed, or re-typed from an image.

Comment: Yeah, *changes* to the code are entirely different. Unless they are trivial change to the execution (e.g., adding a print statement or something), then it's probably best to skip or reject them. It's still a tossup between the two, though - I personally wouldn't reject unless I can at least understand the code. It might be in a language I don't use but I can at least read, so it's usually evident if a change would alter the semantics of the code significantly. And if there is a large enough semantic difference that I can't guarantee behaves the same, I'd reject.

Comment: *Reject or skip any 'to English' translations.* You can safely change that to just 'Reject'. We don't want people suggesting edits that do translations at all so no need to leave it in the queue for someone else to Reject it.

Comment: Not sure if people will want this question to become its own FAQ but here are some existing FAQs on how to do edits that should help you determine whether the edits you're seeing are good ones: [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: Be prepared to do lots of skips if you are uncertain until you get a better feel for it

Comment: Recommended reading for the LQP review queue: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007)